# Finding classes tagged with a custom attribute doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I've used the code from another answer to find classes in an assembly that are tagged with a specific custom attribute:

```
var allClasses = tpAssy.GetTypes();

var testClasses = from t in tpAssy.GetTypes()
                  let attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestClassAttribute), true)
                  where attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0
                  select new { Type = t, Attributes = attributes.Cast<TestClassAttribute>() };
```

However, in my test-case assembly I can see that *allClasses* lists 4 classes, of which three are tagged with the custom attribute (TestClassAttribute) that I am interested in. but the second Linq query assigned to *testClasses* returns an empty enumeration.

Here's the code header for one such class:

```
[TestClass()]
public class BaseSessionTest
{...
```

This is VS2013 with .Net 4.5.

What gives?

Comment: It works fine for me. how do you get the assembly. one way is : `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program));` which `Program` is main class of application for example and can be any other class

Comment: var assyName = new AssemblyName();
                            assyName.CodeBase = string.Concat("file:///", assyPath);
                            assyName.Name = testProject;  

                            Assembly tpAssy = Assembly.Load(assyName); Note that the assembly does indeed contain the classes I am interested in - it's when I try to filter out the ones I'm not interested in that it goes wrong.

Comment: Why dont you use `Assembly.LoadFile(string path)` method?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Because it is deprecated and tpAssy.GetTypes() then throws an exception (FileNotFound exception, even though it is at the specified path). The point though is that the loaded assembly can be seen to contain all the classes, but not when filtered on the custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It's a .Net framework issue. The assembly being loaded was compiled using Visual Studio 2008 (.Net 3.5) and the application that isn't working is .Net 4.6 in Visual Studio 2013. In the latter, reflection clearly doesn't work completely with .net assemblies compiled using earlier frameworks. Is that a bug or is there a secret trick you have to know?

Comment: A guess: .Net doesn't know that the `TestClassAttribute` you refer to in your code is the same as the one that's used in that external assembly.

Comment: Quite possibly. How do I get around that? It looks like reflection doesn't work (reliably) with assemblies compiled against an earlier framework, which is disturbing if true.

Comment: Maybe you can get the Type from the external assembly, by name. And then get the attributes of *that* Type.

Comment: I don't know what the types are - I want every type tagged with the TestClass attribute. There are hundreds of them, all differently named. All I want to do is find all the test classes and all the test methods within each such class.

Comment: I meant: get the type of the *attribute* from the externa assembly instead of your current assembly - there should be just the one (I hope). Then use that Type to filter the classes. The two attributes (local and external) may be named the same, but are in different assemblies - so different types.